# CSS background color issue

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #header-1           {background: red};
            h2#header-1         {background: maroon};
            body h2#header-1    {background: fuchsia};
            .headers            {background: green};
            h2.headers          {background: olive};
            body h2.headers     {background: lime};
            h2                  {background: blue};
            body h2             {background: aqua};
            #header-1           {background: blue};
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2 style="background: orange">Inline rule style</h2>  <!-- orange  --> <!-- orange -->
        <h2 id="header-1">Identity Style</h2>  <!-- maroon  --> <!-- fuchsia -->
        <h2 class="headers">Class Style</h2>   <!-- green  --> <!-- green -->
        <h2>Element Style</h2>   <!-- blue --> <!-- blue  -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Hello, me and a friend were completing some previous past paper exam questions and came across this one relating to how HTML styles elements. We understand that the first element is being styled orange because inline takes priority over the CSS.

However from there we are confused, the 2nd `h2` seems to output red, the 3rd and the 4th don't do anything.

Any help or insight into this would be helpful.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLVF3/

Comment: Do you mean background-color?

Comment: @Rao definitely has the right idea.

Comment: Semi-colons are wrongly placed : `background:red;}` NOT `background:red};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the `;` at the wrong place: behind the `}` instead of inside. Use this CSS:

```css
#header-1           {background: red;}
h2#header-1         {background: maroon;}
body h2#header-1    {background: fuchsia;}
.headers            {background: green;}
h2.headers          {background: olive;}
body h2.headers     {background: lime;}
h2                  {background: blue;}
body h2             {background: aqua;}
#header-1           {background: blue;}
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLVF3/1/

Answer (score 3):

You should be doing this, ie., the `css` should not end with `;` after the rule closes at `}`

A semi-colon in css acts as separator between multiple rules and not as a line terminator. 
[As you have only one css rule under each selector, you can even skip the `;` but it is necessary if you write multiple style rules under a selector.]

```
        <style type="text/css">
            #header-1           {background: red;}
            h2#header-1         {background: maroon;}
            body h2#header-1    {background: fuchsia;}
            .headers            {background: green;}
            h2.headers          {background: olive;}
            body h2.headers     {background: lime;}
            h2                  {background: blue;}
            body h2             {background: aqua;}
            #header-1           {background: blue;}
        </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper syntax, it should not to be closed with ; after } Use this style instead :

```css
#header-1 {background: red;}
h2#header-1 {background: maroon;}
body h2#header-1 {background: fuchsia;}
.headers {background: green;}
h2.headers {background: olive;}
body h2.headers {background: lime;}
h2 {background: blue;}
body h2 {background: aqua;}
#header-1 {background: blue;}
```